# send parameters when call to a stored procedure through SqlMapper.Query in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I have following SP call

```
        public IEnumerable<classfile> GetData(bool isactive)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = this.OpenConnection())
            {

                 IList<classfile> SampleList = SqlMapper.Query<classfile>(cnn, "SPName").ToList();

                cnn.Close();

                return SampleList.ToList();
            }
        }
```

How can I send parameters along with above dapper SP call

I tried following

```
        public IEnumerable<classfile> GetData(bool isactive)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = this.OpenConnection())
            {
                 var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                 parameters.Add("@isActive", isactive);

                 IList<classfile> SampleList = SqlMapper.Query<classfile>(cnn, "SPName", parameters).ToList();

                cnn.Close();

                return SampleList.ToList();
            }
        }
```

but its run time getting error as following

> Procedure or function 'SPName' expects parameter '@isActive', which
>   was not supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer myself

```
    public IEnumerable<classfile> GetData(bool isactive)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cnn = this.OpenConnection())
        {
             DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
             parameters.Add("@isActive", isactive);

             IList<classfile> SampleList = SqlMapper.Query<classfile>(cnn, "SPName", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

            cnn.Close();

            return SampleList.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can write something like this

```
            IList<classfile> SampleList = SqlMapper.Query<classfile>(cnn, "SPName", new
            {
                isActive = isactive
            }
            , commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```